# Show that: $a^4+b^4+c^4<2a^2b^2+2b^2c^2+2a^2c^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, inequality, polynomials, triangles

If $a,b,c$ are triangle sides, show that:

> $$a^4+b^4+c^4<2a^2b^2+2b^2c^2+2a^2c^2$$

It's very similar to $a^2+b^2+c^2≥ab+bc+ac \Rightarrow a^4+b^4+c^4>a^2b^2+b^2c^2+a^2c^2$

I can't continue from here.

Comment: $a^4+b^4+c^4\ge a^2b^2+b^2c^2+a^2c^2$, not $>$. Equality occurs if and only if $a=b=c$. In this case, it's an equilateral triangle.

Comment: @user236182 Have you noticed that a 2 is lacking in your RHS ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Read what OP wrote after the yellow statement.

Comment: @ user236182 OK I hadn't noticed...

Answer (score 3):

Note that the sides of a triangle must satisfy 
\begin{eqnarray*}
a+b-c>0 \\
a-b+c >0 \\
-a+b+c >0 .
\end{eqnarray*}
So
\begin{eqnarray*}
(a+b+c) (a+b-c)(a-b+c)(-a+b+c)>0.
\end{eqnarray*}
Expand this & you will have your inequality.

It is subtly different from 
\begin{eqnarray*}
(a-b)^2 +(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2 >0 \\
a^2+b^2+c^2 > ab+bc+ca.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: $(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2\ge 0$, $a^2+b^2+c^2\ge ab+bc+ca$, not $>$. Equality happens if and only if $a=b=c$. In this case, it's an equilateral triangle.

Answer (score 3):

HİNT:

I've solved this before.

> $$(a+b+c)×(a+b-c)×(b+c-a)×(a+c-b)>0$$

And you will get the required inequality.

Answer (score 2):

The difference betwen LHS and RHS can be written under the form of a determinant:

$$\tag{1}\Delta=\begin{vmatrix}0 &a^2&b^2&1\\a^2&0&c^2&1\\b^2&c^2&0&1\\1&1&1&0\end{vmatrix} = a^4
+b^4+c^4 − 2(a^2b^2+a^2c^2+b^2c^2) $$

$\Delta$ is known as the Cayley-Menger determinant.

Why is $\Delta \leq 0$ ? Because there is a relationship between $\Delta$ and the  area $A$ of the triangle (which is a kind of re-writing of the famous Heron's formula):

$$\tag{2}A^2=\dfrac{-1}{2^2(2!)^2} \Delta$$

(see pages 9-10 of the excellent document (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.02816.pdf).

Remark 1: Due to (2), the given inequality cannot become an equality unless $A=0$, i.e., unless the triangle is flat.

Remark 2: Relationship (1) considered as a quadratic form in $a^2, b^2, c^2$ has rather rich applications. See for example "About the Neuberg-Pedoe and the Oppenheim Inequalities, D. S. Mitrinovic and J. E. Pecaric, Journal of Math. Anal. and Appl. 129, 196-210 (1988)"

Answer (score 2):

$$2(a^2b^2+a^2c^2+b^2c^2)-a^4-b^4-c^4=4a^2b^2-(a^4+b^4+c^4-2a^2c^2-2b^2c^2+2a^2b^2)=$$
$$(2ab)^2-(a^2+b^2-c^2)^2=(2ab-a^2-b^2+c^2)(2ab+a^2+b^2-c^2)=$$
$$=(c^2-(a-b)^2)((a+b)^2-c^2)=(c-a+b)(c+a-b)(a+b-c)(a+b+c)>0.$$